# WebExtensions. Using third party (npm) packages in a personal extension (not for distro)

Tags: javascript, npm, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've been looking into developing a simple Firefox extension that utilizes modules outside of the core sdk (firebase / cheerio). I can't seem to find much info on this sort of thing. I see that there is legacy options (jpm) but it is no longer supported.

Does anyone know if it is at all possible to use `npm` packages inside of a webExtension? Would / could it work if i manually pulled out the core bits of the libraries i want to use and placed them into my own lib folder? I am going to give this a try first. Any resources (current) would be great!

Comment: Why reopen: OP seems to want to know how to do this. Asking for resources might lead reviewers to think these should be off-site, but it was answerable here (the answer gives instructions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a build that bundles your add-on with code of an external npm packen. This can be achieved using [rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup) in combination with [rollup-plugin-node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve) and [rollup-plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs) to resolve CommonJS modules.

The [firefox-addon-skeleton](https://github.com/simomat/firefox-addon-skeleton) includes an example of this solution. It bundles background.js with a rot13 function that comes with an npm package.